# I am using jQuery File Upload in PHP . Its running fine on my local server but doesn't work on live server

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

My PHP Code in the controller Welcome.php file:

```
function uploader(){

     $options = array(
       'upload_dir' => 'uploads/', 
       'upload_url' => base_url().'uploads/',   
       'script_url' => base_url().'Welcome/uploader',     
       //'parameter'  => 'uploads'
    ); 
    $upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);

 }
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(function () {
'use strict';  

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Welcome/uploader'     
});

// Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    'option',
    'redirect',
    window.location.href.replace(
        /\/[^\/]*$/,
        '/cors/result.html?%s'
    )
)
})
```

Comment: The only functionality is not working is the delete button after the upload on the live server , but its working fine on my local server . By the way , when I use inspect element and i saw that there is

Comment: DELETE  http://www.waxworks.com/drakedas/Welcome/uploader?file=4362dce5-af38-4e89-bb5f-87f82b7a3ef9.jpg 404 (Not Found)     send @ jquery.min.js:5m.